# Removing BizTalk Assemblies using Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have made a console with a number of features regarding applications, ports and so forth.

I am using the Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM assembly as an interface for the biztalk database.

The point is that the assembly seems slightly "incomplete" since i dont find any way to remove assemblies(or resources as they are called in administration console) from an application.

Is there anyone out there who has the solution for this?
(Preferably without doing any manual database hacks)

Ive been searching around for a bit both on google and here but im surprized nobody else seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [RemoveResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561331.aspx) command provided by btstask.exe. Example:

```
BTSTask RemoveResource /ApplicationName:MyApplication /Luid:"MyApp.Orchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789ABCDEF"
```

For programmatic invocation of btstask.exe:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("btstask.exe", "RemoveResource /ApplicationName:" +     application + " /Luid:\"" + assemblyPath + "\"");
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Beware using the [MSBTS_DeploymentService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578176%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) WMI class, which was commonly used in BizTalk 2004 for doing what you are trying to achieve, as it does not support the concept of an Application container.

Comment: Ahh, didn´t think about invoking another program.
Though it would certainly be nicer if microsoft could keep it all in one place...
Thanks a lot!